# Laravel 5 queue:listen setting differ from queue:work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, supervisord

I'm running a queue in Laravel for my parser program. I use the database driver in the queue.php config and set the expire to 3600. The queue is maintained using supervisord. Here is the supervisor configuration for the queue program:

```
[program:laravel_queue]
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:listen --memory=2048 --timeout=600
user=mainuser
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/laraqueue.out.log
```

This is what shows up when I searched for PHP processes that was currently running :

```
/usr/bin/php artisan queue:work  --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=2048 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=local
grep php
php /var/www/html/artisan queue:listen --memory=2048 --timeout=600
```

My problem is that when I use the queue, it always timed out when it reached 60 seconds, even though I already set --timeout=600. And I noticed that the timeout setting didn't show up in the queue:work process. Can anyone help me on this?